# How can I change the direction of scrolling in parallax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, parallax

I changed something in my code yesterday, and now the parallax picture is scrolling in the opposite direction. I went through my git commits but can't seem to figure out why the image is moving in the wrong direction. I'm using jquery.parallax-1.1.3.

Jquery plugin:

```
/*
Plugin: jQuery Parallax
Version 1.1.3
Author: Ian Lunn
Twitter: @IanLunn
Author URL: http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/
Plugin URL: http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/

Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
*/

(function( $ ){
    var $window = $(window);
    var windowHeight = $window.height();

    $window.resize(function () {
        windowHeight = $window.height();
    });

    $.fn.parallax = function(xpos, speedFactor, outerHeight) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var getHeight;
        var firstTop;
        var paddingTop = 0;

        //get the starting position of each element to have parallax applied to it
        $this.each(function(){
            firstTop = $this.offset().top;
        });

        if (outerHeight) {
            getHeight = function(jqo) {
                return jqo.outerHeight(true);
            };
        } else {
            getHeight = function(jqo) {
                return jqo.height();
            };
        }

        // setup defaults if arguments aren't specified
        if (arguments.length < 1 || xpos === null) xpos = "50%";
        if (arguments.length < 2 || speedFactor === null) speedFactor = 0.1;
        if (arguments.length < 3 || outerHeight === null) outerHeight = true;

        // function to be called whenever the window is scrolled or resized
        function update(){
            var pos = $window.scrollTop();

            $this.each(function(){
                var $element = $(this);
                var top = $element.offset().top;
                var height = getHeight($element);

                // Check if totally above or totally below viewport
                if (top + height < pos || top > pos + windowHeight) {
                    return;
                }

                $this.css('backgroundPosition', xpos + " " + Math.round((firstTop - pos) * speedFactor) + "px");
            });
        }

        $window.bind('scroll', update).resize(update);
        update();
    };
})(jQuery);
```

My implementation:

```
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  $('#home').css({'background-attachment': 'scroll'});
} else {
  $('#home').parallax('50%', 0.1);
}
```

Comment: And how can we figure it out if we can't see your code?

Comment: Good point. Since the plugin is open source and widely popular, I thought people were already familiar with it. I edited it into my answer above.

Comment: Not the code from the library, your code where you implemented it.

Comment: I edited it into the question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. The problem was in the stylesheet as I had suspected. Added this to my stylesheet:

```
#home {
  background-color: #222;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
  padding: 0;
}
```